# CSS background Повторяющийся фон в шахматном порядке?

Tags: html, css, svg, background

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как средствами CSS создать повторяющийся фон, но со смещенной картинкой?
Приведу простой пример:

```css
html{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #CBDBFE url("data:image/svg+xml, <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 100 100' width='100' height='100'><path d='M12.5 12.6H89v76.5H12.5z'/></svg>") 0 0 repeat;

}
```

Как сделать чтобы объект повторялся со смещением?
 Например, чтобы клетки шли в шахматном порядке?
Я пробовал увеличить ширину в два раза, но CSS заполняет построчно, и нужного результата я не добился.
 Вопрос не про шахматный `background`, а именно про повторяющийся фон со смещением картинки, которая  повторяется.

Comment: а на linear-gradient не вариант ?

Comment: саму картинку делать со смещением внутри svg. Или множественные фоны использовать.

Comment: Смещение внутри svg не решило проблему.

Comment: https://habr.com/post/111228/

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как нарисовать простую шахматную доску?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/597561/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%88%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%83)

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, по ссылке всё сделано через js. В этом вопросе нет js, так что не думаю что это дубликат

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, если использовать именно svg:

```css
html{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #CBDBFE 
      url("data:image/svg+xml, <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 200 200' width='200' height='200'> <rect x='10' y='10' width='80' height='80' fill='#000' /><rect x='110' y='110' width='80' height='80' fill='#000'/></svg>") 
      0 0 repeat;

}
```

Comment: ачто тут находится в сниппете ? просто сиреневый фон ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, http://prntscr.com/k0tylz вот что тут

Comment: в Лисе не работает

Comment: Как быть если изображение, хоть и SVG но несколько сложнее чем просто прямогугольник, и нету возможности дублировать копию ? (*По поводу не отображения в Лисе - там надо делать кодирование кода svg http://foxtools.ru/UrlEncoder ) На сколько я помню теги defs и use так не запихнешь

Comment: Не работает, просто голубой фон.

Comment: @Duoxx, в хроме все работает!

Comment: Ну знаешь ли, не все хромом пользуются.

Comment: @Duoxx, ну знаете ли, вопрос был об svg в фоне! В ответе ясно обозначено - "НАПРИМЕР" (т.е. как один из всевозможных вариантов)! Если вас что-то не устраивает - предлагайте свой ответ!

Answer (score 4):

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 74%, black 75%, black), linear-gradient( 45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 74%, black 75%, black);
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  background-position: 0 0, 50px 50px;
}
```