# Фильтр концентрического уменьшения прозрачности ?

Tags: css, css3, svg

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли просто средствами CSS или SVG сделать некий фильтр наложения на фоновое изображения, что бы оно радиально уходило в 0 по прозрачности ?

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 74%, black 75%, black), linear-gradient( 45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 74%, black 75%, black);
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  background-position: 0 0, 50px 50px;
}
```

Я хочу получить что-то похожее на [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Единственное, что необходим плавный переход (без ступенчатых рывков).

Comment: а где svg ? у вас есть тег svg в вопросе, я вижу в вашем вопросе только тот пример что не устроил как решение в прошлом вашем вопросе но вижу что именно его вы применяете

Comment: Изображение для background взял из прошлого, поскольку лень было выдумывать что-то новое. (Это маловажно, там может быть и jpg и png картинка), важен фильтр который будет накладываться поверх. (Если такой впринципе существует)

Comment: для svg снизу решение

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать `css mask`(привет IE)

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
}
body{
  background-color:#cda;
}
.mask {
  height:100vh;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient( 45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 74%, black 75%, black),
    linear-gradient( 45deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 74%, black 75%, black);
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  background-position: 0 0, 50px 50px;
  -webkit-mask:radial-gradient(circle at center,transparent,black);
}
```

```html
<div class="mask"></div>
```

Можно нарисовать в svg

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}
svg{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:50vw;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice">
  <defs>
    <radialGradient id="gradient" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="rgba(0,0,0,0)" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#fff" />
    </radialGradient>
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="1000" height="500" fill="url(#gradient)" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <pattern id="pattern" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" />
    <rect x="50" y="0" width="50" height="50" fill="white" />
    <rect x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50" />
    <rect x="0" y="50" width="50" height="50" fill="white" />
  </pattern>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="1000" height="500" fill="url(#pattern)" mask="url(#mask)" />
</svg>

<h3>Либо для произвольной картинки(используется маска из предыдущего svg)</h3>

<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 500" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice">
  <image preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" xlink:href="https://www.placecage.com/c/200/300" x="0" y="0" width="1000" height="500" mask="url(#mask)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: svg-фильтр создать наверняка можно, но его поддержка у html-элементов будет как у `css-mask`. Поэтому два вышеупомянутых способа считаю самыми оптимальными.

Answer (score 3):

Вот так годится?

```css
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
  background-image: 
    radial-gradient(circle at 50%, white, transparent 142%),
    linear-gradient(45deg, black 24%, transparent 25%, transparent 74%, black 75%, black),
    linear-gradient(45deg, black 24%, transparent 25%, transparent 74%, black 75%, black);
  background-size: 100% 100%, 100px 100px, 100px 100px;
  background-position: 0 0, 50px 50px;
}
```

PS: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/597824/178988

Comment: Нужна именно прозрачность(альфа канал), а не радиальный градиент. Фоновое изображение может быть любым