# css градиент который растворяет элемент

Tags: css, градиент

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]у меня есть элемент с bacground-color и внутри этого элемента есть полупрозрачный круг, и мне надо чтобы этот круг растворялся но я не могу найти css свойство для этого

Comment: понятнее не придумаешь

Comment: если бы вы добавили картинку, может бы что-то прояснилось

Comment: Полагаю, вам надо что-то аля `background:radial-gradient(ellipse at center, color1  0%, color2 100%);`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/850940/275019 что-то вроде такого?

Comment: добавил фото, чтобы он к низу растворялся

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body, .bg, .circle {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.bg {
  width:700px;
  height:195px;
  transform:skew(0, 3deg);
  top:-20px;
  background: linear-gradient(55deg, 
                              #ba5bb7 0%, 
                              #773ecf 100%);
                              
}

.circle {
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 400px;
 height: 400px;
 background: linear-gradient(0deg, 
                             rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 0%, 
                             rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 30%, 
                             rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
<div class="circle" style="left:550px;top:-100px"></div>
<div class="circle" style="left:250px;top:20px"></div>
```

Comment: нужно чтобы нижняя часть пропадала, а не центр

Comment: @ЭмильКулуев поменял градиент